# Blank page in landscape environment with overpic

Tags: landscape, overpic

I have an unwanted blank page when inserting an overpic in landscape environment. I tried the afterpage-package as well as some different things (like \clearpage command etc). Nothing seems to help but changing the scale of the first overpic to 0.7. As you can image, this is not what I want, since I need the overpic to be readable (and I need an overpic, because I want to put checkmarks on the background-pdf).

Here's my example code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\newgeometry{margin=0.3cm}

\begin{landscape}

  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \thispagestyle{empty}

    \begin{overpic}[scale=1.0]{landscape.pdf}
    \end{overpic}

    \begin{overpic}[scale=1.0]{landscape.pdf}
    \end{overpic}

\end{landscape}

\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

The landscape.pdf can be found here: https://www.wpi.edu/sites/default/files/docs/Events/Annual-Events/landscape.pdf

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Maybe the image is to big. Could you reproduce the problem with an `example-image-a` (`\begin{overpic}[scale=2.0]{example-image-a}`), which could be arbitrary scaled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is indeed that the included image is larger than the page boundaries. Trying to fit the image to the available space, LaTeX breaks the page and then giving up to find a better position. Using `margin=0.0cm` and and a scale that is not quite 1.0 could help.

However, I would propose a different way: Instead of *writing on an image* (the `overpic` approach), try to *add an image in the background*. You can use the `background` package for that.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\checkmark}{\ding{52}}

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\backgroundsetup{scale=1, angle=0, opacity=1.0}

\newenvironment{onimage}[1]{%
    \begin{landscape}%
    \pagestyle{empty}%
    \backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperheight, height=\paperwidth, angle=90, keepaspectratio]{#1}}}%
    \BgThispage%
}{%
    \end{landscape}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{onimage}{example-image-a}
    \Large Just a test
\end{onimage}

\begin{onimage}{landscape}
    \Large~\\[6.3cm]\hspace*{4cm}\checkmark
    \\[0.1cm]\hspace*{4cm}\checkmark
\end{onimage}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

And two of the output pages:
[image]

Please note:

- Due to the rotation with `\begin{landscape}`, the settings for the background image look weird with the widths and heights exchanged - it only makes sense in the rotated environment!
- This only works properly if there is some text on each page, otherwise the background image will flush to the next filled page. So if you want to have the background image only on one page, remember to add a `~` at the appropriate place.
- I added some checkmarks just to illustrate how one could proceed.
- I defined a new environment `onimage` that takes the picture name as argument, to make it easier for you to use this with different pictures. However, you will certainly want to adjust its definition to your specific needs.

Comment: I see what you mean. But this would mean having the same background image all the time, right? In my case, I have like 60 different pdf-pages I need to write on (or at least placing a checkmark ;) ). Thats why I chose overpic, seemed to be more easy at the beginning.

Comment: You can easily call `\backgroundsetup{contents=...}` many times within the document. I updated the answer to include a way to do that without much effort.